# use a button to fetch a index in core data

Tags: swift, button, core-data, indexing, fetch

My swift code below would like to use a button to go to the first photo in the index. My code works if the user types 0 into the tetxtfield. Then the image view fetches the first item saved in the index. What I want to do is when the user presses rghtBtn, it will have the effect as entering 0.Then if it is pressed again it fetches the 2nd item in the index. So it is constant increasing the index. The user is fetching a binary data called pic. I have a photo of binary data.

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    lazy var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


    var itemsName : [NSManagedObject] = []

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        guard let text = (textField.text as? NSString)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string), let index = Int(text) else {
            return true
        }
        loadImage(at: index - 1 )

//        currentPageLabel.text = tt.text

        let ee = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)



        return true
    }


    func loadImage(at index : Int) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "idx == %d", Int32(index))
        do {
            if let user = try context.fetch(fetchRequest).first {
                pic.image = UIImage(data: user.pic!)
            } else {
                pic.image = UIImage(named: "np.png")

            }
        } catch {
            print("Could not fetch \(error) ")
        }


    }


    var pic = UIImageView()
    var tt = UITextField()
    var lzbel = UILabel()

    var submit = UIButton()


    var leftBtn = UIButton()
    var rightBtn = UIButton()



    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       let item = Users(context: context)
          let vex = UIImage(named: "lili.jpg")!.pngData()
          item.pic = vex
          item.idx = 0

          let item2 = Users(context: context)
          let vex2 = UIImage(named: "camila.jpg")!.pngData()
          item2.pic = vex2
          item2.idx = 1

          print("Storing Data..")
          do {
              try context.save()
          } catch {
              print("Storing data Failed", error)
        }

        lzbel.textAlignment = .center


        tt.placeholder = "Enter Page Number"
        tt.delegate = self
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        [pic,tt,rightBtn].forEach{
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.backgroundColor = .green
        }

        pic.backgroundColor = .red




        rightBtn.setTitle(">", for: .normal)
        tt.textAlignment = .center


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([


            tt.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant :0),
            tt.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant : 0),
            tt.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3, constant: 0),
            tt.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),

             tt.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 7/7, constant: 0),







            pic.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant :0),
            pic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tt.bottomAnchor, constant : 0),
            pic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.33, constant: 0),
            pic.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),



            rightBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant :0),
               rightBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pic.bottomAnchor, constant : 0),
               rightBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.33, constant: 0),
               rightBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),







        ])

        tt.backgroundColor = .systemGray


        submit.backgroundColor = .purple
        submit.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)


        let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Users")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "idx", ascending: true)]


        do {
            itemsName = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)



        }catch {
            print("Ashley Tisdale")
        }



        lzbel.text = String(itemsName.count) + String(" total pages saved")



        lzbel.backgroundColor = .red

        rightBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rightBtnPress), for: .touchDown)

    }


    @objc func rightBtnPress(){
        //Hiting this code should have the effect


    }









}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Couple questions, where are you defining and updating the `index` that you pass to `loadImage` in `rightBtn`? How did you configure your button? Is `rghtBtn` even being called.

Comment: @koen updated my question above added a gif. As you can see in the gif. When the user taps the button nothing happens but when the user types 1 into a textfield a image is fetch and displayed in a image view. I want the first tap of the button to have the exact same effect as the user typing 1 into the textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an index variable.

```
var counter = 0
```

Then in `rightBtnPress` load the image at index `counter` and increment the variable.

```
@objc func rightBtnPress() {
   loadImage(at: counter)
   counter += 1
}
```